# Better scrolling between divs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

SEE BELOW QUESTION FOR ANSWER:

**QUESTION**

So I have a javascript on my webpage to scroll between the divs, but I was hoping to improve it. It assigns a class (`.current`) to any div which has class `.section` and cycles up or down these if the buttons are clicked. It also has a sort of hackish workaround for getting to/from the top of the page, since the `.next()` operator won't move between parent and child elements. I don't really want to change the semantic structure of the html, which is more or less as follows:

```
<header>HEADER</header>
<section id="about">ABOUT</section>
<section id="posts">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="section">CONTENT</div>
    <div class="section">CONTENT</div>
    <div class="section">CONTENT</div>
    <div class="section">CONTENT</div>
    <div class="section">CONTENT</div>
</section>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

Firstly, is there any way this can be made more elegant? Using `return;` to abandon the script for the first scroll seems a poor solution but I can't think of any other (and it works).

Secondly, this script currently doesn't account for users scrolling by *not* using the buttons, and as such the up button can make the page scroll down, if the user has scrolled up past the `div.current`, and vice versa. Is there a way of finding out what the topmost `div.section` *visible* to the user is, and assigning the `.current` class to it before the script executes?

Go easy, I'm horrible at coding, and this is one of my first real shots at doing something that's not just a copy and paste!

Script is below:

```
$('div.section').first().addClass('current');
$('a.scroll').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        var top = $(this).offset();
        var height = $(window).height();
        var t = $(this).attr('id'),
        that = $(this);

       if (t === 'scrolldown' && top.top < height){        
           $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.top').offset().top }, 'slow');
           return;
     } 
       if (t === 'scrolldown' && $('.current').next('div.section').length > 0) {
          var $next = $('.current').next('.section');

          $('.current').removeClass('current');     
          $next.addClass('current');
          $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.current').offset().top }, 'slow');
     }
       if (t === 'scrollup' && $('.current').prev('div.top').length > 0){        
          $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
          return;
     } 
       if (t === 'scrollup' && $('.current').prev('div.section').length > 0) {
          var $prev = $('.current').prev('.section');

          $('.current').removeClass('current');
          $prev.addClass('current');
          $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.current').offset().top }, 'slow');
     }
});
```

**ANSWER**

This was finally achieved using the [jQuery onScreen plugin](https://github.com/benpickles/onScreen) and a bit of trial and error. It can be seen in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2aJ6M/) This code works, but it is not pretty and I'm sure it could be improved:

```
// onScreen jQuery plugin v0.2.1
// (c) 2011-2013 Ben Pickles
//
// http://benpickles.github.io/onScreen
//
// Released under MIT license.
(function(a){a.expr[":"].onScreen=function(b){var c=a(window),d=c.scrollTop(),e=c.height(),f=d+e,g=a(b),h=g.offset().top,i=g.height(),j=h+i;return h>=d&&h<f||j>d&&j<=f||i>e&&h<=d&&j>=f}})(jQuery);

// My Code
$('div.section').first().addClass('current');
$('a.scroll').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.current').removeClass('current');     
    $('.section').filter(':onScreen').first().addClass('current');

        var top = $(this).offset();
        var height = $(window).height();
        var t = $(this).attr('id'),
        that = $(this);
    if (t === 'scrolldown' && top.top < height){        

        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.top').offset().top }, 'slow');
        return;
  } 
    if (t === 'scrolldown' && $('.current').next('div.section').length > 0) {

        var $next = $('.current').next('.section');
        $('.current').removeClass('current');     
        $next.addClass('current');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.current').offset().top }, 'slow');
        return;

  }
    if (t === 'scrollup' && $('.current')[0].getBoundingClientRect().top < 0) {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.current').offset().top }, 'slow');

        return;
  }

    if (t === 'scrollup' && $('.current').prev('div.section').length > 0) {
        var $prev = $('.current').prev('.section');
        $('.current').removeClass('current');
        $prev.addClass('current');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.current').offset().top }, 'slow');
        return;
  }
    if (t === 'scrollup' && $('.current').prev('div.top').length > 0){        

        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
        return;
  } 
});
```

Comment: `$(function () {` in else condition? Remove all the `ready()` from `if-else`

Comment: @RohanKumar What were they for? Who knows what I was thinking... thanks.

Comment: Exactly, nobody knows what you are thinking, but it was not the right way to use `ready()`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Just a scroll over your title area? If so, you should just fix it on the page and let the rest of the page scroll.

Comment: @Malcoda Sorry if the post isn't clear. I've more or less achieved the result that I hoped for (see link) except that a) I have had to include the two extra if cases to scroll up to the top and down from the top, and b) that when a user scrolls up or down the page normally, the script doesn't know this. That means that the up and down buttons can actually move the page in the opposite direction in some circumstances which is not ideal. I'm currently looking at integrating https://github.com/benpickles/onScreen, but not quite sure how yet.